# pgAdmin throwing "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notifies')" when running SELECT query with PostGIS geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I have been running queries using pgAdmin on tables that include geometry. If I run a SELECT query that includes the geometry field, I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notifies')`. If I exclude the geometry field, the query runs without issue. QGIS is able to display the data just fine, and I'm able to run queries with the geometry field through Python. So this seems like a pgAdmin issue, but not quite sure what to do about it since the queries were working, then they weren't.

Update and other queries that do not return a direct result set are running fine.

Ran SELECT queries using the context menu for each table (**View/Edit Data > All Rows**). Got error message.

Manually typed SELECT query including geometry field (e.g., `select state_geo, state_code, state_name, geom from states`). Got error message.

Excluded geometry field from SELECT query (`select state_geo, state_code, state_name from states`). Achieved expected result.